# regular expression: extract part of url and create new column in r

Tags: r, regex, url

I have records of URL and I want to extract part of it and create new columns. In my example, I would like to consider the number after `"groups"` as `group_id` and the number of `dicussion_topics` as `discussion_id`
df like:

```
 user  url
    1      "https://test.com/groups/3276/discussion_topics/3939"
    2      "https://test.com/groups/34/discussion_topics/11"
    3      "https://test.com/groups/3276"
    4      "https://test.com/groups/other"
```

I want result like

```
user  group_id  dicussion_id  
1      3276       3939
2      34         11
3      3276       NA
4      NA         NA
```

How can I do it with the regular expression in R?
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat$group_id=as.numeric(sub(".*/groups/(\\d+).*|.*","\\1",dat$url))
dat$discussion=as.numeric(sub(".*/discussion_topics/(\\d+).*|.*","\\1",dat$url))
dat
  user                                                 url group_id discussion
1    1 https://test.com/groups/3276/discussion_topics/3939     3276       3939
2    2     https://test.com/groups/34/discussion_topics/11       34         11
3    3                        https://test.com/groups/3276     3276         NA
4    4                       https://test.com/groups/other       NA         NA
```

Comment: thank you so much, would you explain about \\d and \\1?

Comment: \d stands for digit, the + for 1 or more; \d is enclosed in brackets marking it as capturing group; \1 is the backreference to the first capturing group to be extracted. If there would be more than one such group you could extract both, e.g., in switched order as in string by \2\1. You might have a look at [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) or similar pages for further details.

Comment: @Cina look at Manuel's response

Answer (score 1):

Another version with `stringi` package and lookbehind regex

Update: Admittedly, the function of @Onyambu is faster. See the benchmark.
Update2: Added the third version the benchmark. No improvement concerning speed.

```
library(stringi)
extract_info = function(x) {
  x$group = stri_extract_all_regex(x$url, "(?<=groups/)\\d+")
  x$topic = stri_extract_all_regex(x$url, "(?<=discussion_topics/)\\d+")
  x
}
extract_info(dat)
#    user                                                 url group topic
# 1    1 https://test.com/groups/3276/discussion_topics/3939  3276  3939
# 2    2     https://test.com/groups/34/discussion_topics/11    34    11
# 3    3                        https://test.com/groups/3276  3276    NA
# 4    4                       https://test.com/groups/other    NA    NA

extract_info2 = function(dat) {
dat$group_id=as.numeric(sub(".*/groups/(\\d+).*|.*","\\1",dat$url))
dat$discussion=as.numeric(sub(".*/discussion_topics/(\\d+).*|.*","\\1",dat$url))
dat
}

extract_info3 = function(data) {
  df$group_id <- as.numeric(regmatches(df$url, gregexpr(".*groups/*\\K.\\d+", df$url, perl=TRUE)))
  df$discussion <- as.numeric(regmatches(df$url, gregexpr(".*topics/*\\K.\\d+", df$url, perl=TRUE)))
  df
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  extract_info(dat)
  ,extract_info2(dat)
  ,extract_info3(dat)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#            expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# extract_info(dat)  152.769 160.269 172.1629 170.5325 176.0590  300.011   100
# extract_info2(dat)  99.872 106.386 120.9876 117.2415 125.7285  226.981   100
# extract_info3(dat) 285.799 301.984 378.7235 308.8925 323.3000 6684.297   100
```

Comment: great thx. I can't understand why the regular expression is different in each answer

Comment: With regex you have to specify a suitable pattern, depending on your string you several patterns may apply to get what you want, e.g., to extract "abc" from "101abc101", you might erase all numbers via gsub(\\d,"",..), or extract the sequence of letters with capturing group gsub("(^.*)(abc)(.*$), "\\2",...) or .... many other options (did not run the code, maybe erroneous, just for explaining the idea). So the task is to find an intelligent matching pattern that is fast in matching.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
df$group_id <- as.numeric(regmatches(df$url, gregexpr(".*groups/*\\K.\\d+", df$url, perl=TRUE)))
df$discussion <- as.numeric(regmatches(df$url, gregexpr(".*topics/*\\K.\\d+", df$url, perl=TRUE)))
```